# How to modify part of an object in array using map in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to take an array of objects like so

```
[
   { url: 'some url here', clickHandler: 'click handler function'},
   { url: 'some other url here', clickHandler: 'other clickHandler function'}
]
```

I want to pull apart the url of the object and run each url through a function that returns the modified url and return an array like this

```
[
   { url: 'some modified url here', clickHandler: 'click handler function'},
   { url: 'some other modified url here', clickHandler: 'other clickHandler function'}
]
```

I know that I want to use .map because I can iterate over the array of objects but I am unsure how to create the new array to have the same structure but just modify the url as necessary. The function is just going to return the modified url.

UPDATE: I don’t want to use forEach because the original array needs to remain intact.

Comment: "I don’t want to use forEach because the original array needs to remain intact" it really depends on what you do in the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply return map the array objects as they are except by calling the function that you want to change the url:

```
var output = input.map(obj => {
  return {
    url: changeUrl(obj.url),
    clickHandler: obj.clickHandler
  }
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/kuhbv07h/)**

Comment: I was thinking something like this but I wasn’t 100% sure if it was the right way to go. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Easy trick would be:

```
var newArray = oldArray.map(function(el) {
    el.url = 'new url';   // change url

    return el;          // return whole modified element
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.map()` to construct a new object on the fly and return it -

```js
let arr = [

  {
    url: "http://www.foo.com",
    func: () => console.log("Hi")
  },
  {
    url: "http://www.bar.com",
    func: () => console.log("Hi")
  }
];


let modifiedArr = arr.map(e => ({
  url: e['url'] + '/baz',
  func: e['func']
}));

console.log(modifiedArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `.map()` with `Object.assign()` so that you don't need to hard code all properties.

```js
var data = [
   { url: 'some url here', clickHandler: 'click handler function'},
   { url: 'some other url here', clickHandler: 'other clickHandler function'}
];

var result = data.map(obj =>
  Object.assign({}, obj, {url: obj.url + " MODIFIED"})
);

console.log(result);
```

Now if the object structure changes, you don't need to update your code.